# How i can made a box in a webpage using HTML5

Tags: html, css

I want to make a C.V using html5 and css3 but I cannot made a cheque(box) please tell me which tag is used for drawing a line

Answer (score 0):

You can create a box using html5 just by calling the **(div)** element inside html & you need to paste this coding inside your css

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    background:   orange;
    border: 25px solid green;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
}
```